# Sunlight reflectors

Tags: led

I am trying to display LEDs on a panel exposed to sunlight and they are hardly visible. What kind of reflectors can be used to make them visible? e.g. Tow truck lighting, sign displays etc

---

The LEDs are mounted on clothing similar to reflective vest.. and are programmable Ws2813. The target  colors are BLUE, RED, YELLOW, WHITE, and possibly green. No fixed position for the wearer. One thing that is wrong is I have a reflective band. I will use black.

Comment: Can you mount them so that the diodes are directly visible?  That will work better than using a reflector.

Comment: Also, use a black background, e.g., https://takemy.money/musou-black-the-new-blackest-paint-in-the-world , to increase contrast. Set the LED's below the surface to avoid direct sun glare.

Comment: Renald, there's a whole chapter I could write on this topic. It would include sections on (1) choice of LED color, (2) luminance contrast and index, (3) chrominance contrast and index, (4) front surface reflection and 1/4 wave optically coated glass surfaces, (5) polarization, and (6) baffling. And when I mean a chapter... I mean dozens of long pages worth. That would be just general info. If you wanted it cast into specific circumstances, such as those you start out suggesting, then this could roll into many times that. Provide ***one*** exact circumstance.

Comment: Please provide more information. What color(s) are the LEDs. Is there anything else on the panel (if possible, show a photo). Does it have other resictions (size? weight?) HOW visible does it have to be (i.e. from a distance)?

Comment: LEDs used for displays in sunlit circumstances used to suffer from two criticisms:
 - Low light output (no longer true.) - Poor attention to contrast (still true.) The 1st derivative of color discrim. in human vision suggests peaks at \$480 \:\text{nm}\$ and at \$585\:\text{nm}\$. Blue or a yellowish-orange LED color. So yellowish-orange is usually preferred for sunlit circums. You will want: - as high a contrast possible between the illumination and surroundings, and; - minimize contrast between non-illumnation and surroundings, and - provide the highest ON/OFF contrast for the LED emitters.